# Pushwoosh with Ionic

Tags: integration, ionic-framework, pushwoosh

I have used Pushwoosh successfully with Phonegap and Cordova, but now I have changed to Ionic, because I think that I can do more stuff with that framework.

But now, I have trouble setting up Pushwoosh with Ionic. I have made a separate file with the initPushwoosh function and included it at the index.html file, and also made a script tag with the initPushwoosh() function, but it doesn't seem to work.

I can see that I am connecting to Pushwoosh at the Dashboard, but after 2-3 seconds, it disconnects. I don't really know what I am doing wrong. If there are someone who successfully integrated Ionic with Pushwoosh, I would appreciate it, if they could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Pushwoosh published a sample for Ionic platform. Worth mentioning a a possible solution for the problem.

https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-cordova-sample/tree/master/Ionic